# LoF, LoT and bibliography in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I would like to include the LoF, LoT and bibliography into my ToC, without a "chapter number", but with the page numbers. I have found solutions, but not for the class I am using, which is report.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

This is my code, I shortened it as best as I could:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%Seitenlayout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}

%Deutsche Umlaute
\usepackage{ngerman}

%Zitierungen in der richtigen Reihenfolge
\usepackage{cite} 

%Längenangaben für den Abstand zwischen zwei Absätzen. 
\usepackage{parskip} 

%Zeilenabstand ändern
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 

%Farbige Texte etc
\usepackage{color} 

%Graphiken und Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%Tabellenumgebung
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} %\toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule

%Mathematische Symbole und Zeichen
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

%Algorithm Package
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

%Blindtext
\usepackage{blindtext}

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Makro Abstract
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\newcommand{\Abstract}{
This is an abstract.\\

\textit{\textbf{Anmerkung:}\\
Der Abstract ist bei Arbeiten, die neben dem deutschen einen englischen Titel haben, verpflichtend.}
}


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Anfang von Dokumententext
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Einbettung des Abstracts
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\chapter*{Abstract}
\chaptermark{Abstract}
\Abstract
\cleardoublepage


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Verzeichnisse
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 
\newpage

% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Beginn des Inhalts
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Einleitung}
\blindtext

\section{Dies ist ein Unterkapitel} 
\blindtext

\section{Tabellen}
Hier ist eine Tabelle gegeben.
\begin{table}[th]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
Ort & Temperatur  & Luftfeuchtigkeit  \\ \hline
Bochum & $16^\circ \text{C}$ & $60 \%$ \\ 
M\"unchen  & $19^\circ \text{C}$ & $62 \%$ \\ 
Berlin  & $14^\circ \text{C}$ & $63 \%$ \\
Frankfurt  & $15^\circ \text{C}$ & $64 \%$ \\  
\end{tabular} \caption[Darstellung der Temperatur und der Luftfeuchtigkeit am 22.09.2012]{Darstellung der Temperatur und der Luftfeuchtigkeit am 22.09.2012 an ausgew\"ahlten Orten in Deutschland. Die erste Spalte ist links ausgerichtet, die zweite zentriert und die dritte ist rechts ausgerichtet.}\label{tab:TempUndLuftfeuchtigkeit}
\end{table}
Tabelle \ref{tab:TempUndLuftfeuchtigkeit} kann mit dem Befehl \verb|\ref{EinEindeutigerName}| einfach referenziert werden.

\section{Abbildungen}

\begin{figure}[th]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\textwidth]{./figures/pt1.eps}}
\caption{Diese Abbildung zeigt die Sprungantworten eines $\text{PT}_1$ und eines $\text{PT}_2$-Gliedes. }
\end{figure} 

\section{Literaturverwaltung}

Beispiel: Der Artikel von Bemporad et al.~\cite{Bemporad2002} gibt eine gute \"Ubersicht \"uber explizite Modellpr\"adiktive Regelung. 

Jones2006b \cite{Jones2006b}


%Bibliography
% \nocite{*} %Wird verwendet um eine Literaturquelle im Verzeichnis erscheinen zu lassen, ohne auf sie im Text zu verweisen. 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvdin}
\bibliography{Masterarbeit_Bibliothek_CN}   
\end{document}
```

In near future I would also like to incorporate a glossary and a symbol directory, but I haven't found out how to do that, yet. Maybe someone has also an advice in which direction I should look for?

Comment: if you willing replace `report` document class with `book` and have document content before first chapter roman numerate, than your problem is soled by inserting command `\frontmatter` before chapter "abstract" and `\mainmatter` before chapter "Einleitung".

Comment: @Zarko Thank you! I solved the problem with the other proposal, but I very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tocbibind` package

```
\usepackage[notindex]{tocbibind}
```

which will add the ToC, LoF, LoT, Bibliography to the ToC but not add the Index if there is one. The package option `nottoc` disables the inclusion of the ToC in itself. Read the manual (`> texdoc tocbibind`) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was searching for :)